# Converting NSObject to CSharp objects throws exception in Debug mode

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, type-conversion, nsobject

After upgrading Xamarin to the latest version (Version 6.3 build 863) casting an NSObject to WebSkriptObject throws an InvalidCastException. However in release-mode (debug info set to 'none') the cast works as expected.

With the previous version of Xamarin everything was ok.
Operating System: Mac 10.12.4
It works after downgrading Xamarin.Mac from 3.2 to 3.0.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: I see no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Xamarin.Mac and it is fixed with Xamarin.Mac 3.5.0.126 (current alpha build)